# Cross Platform Encoding of Encrypted Strings in PHP and OSX

Tags: php, swift, macos, post, encryption

Im encrypting a string in PHP using the following code

```
<?php
    $key256 = "323";
    $iv128 = "2424";
    $text = "ABC";

    $blocksize = 16;
    $len = strlen($text);
    $pad = $blocksize - ($len % $blocksize);

    $text .= str_repeat("0", $pad);

    $cipher = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key256, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv128);

    echo $cipher;

?>
```

In SWIFT I use POST Request and get the data from the server and print out the fetched data to the console like this

```
 var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/test.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let akey:String =  txt_key.stringValue;
        let email:String = txt_email.stringValue
        let VAL:String="test"        
        var data="blah"


        let postString = data
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")

            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding:  .utf8)
            print(responseString)
        }
        task.resume()
```

This keeps printing `nil` even when the Web Browser shows the encrypted string.

What I'm I doing wrong?

**Update**

*I have set the app transport security and stuff in the info.plist and the printing works correctly if I don't use encryption in php*

Comment: Did you add the `App Transport Security Settings` key  in info.plist?

Comment: @UsmanJaved Yes.. it's working if I don't encrypt the string ...